# Overload + Operator for PointF

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, operator-overloading

I am new to c# and windows programming. I know that in c#, there is an awesome feature called operator overloading. I want to apply this technique in my code. In the following code, I want to define the binary `+` operator so that I can concatenate two `PointF` objects.

In the line `pointList.Add(point + center)`, I got an error:

> Error 1   Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'System.Drawing.PointF' and
>   'System.Drawing.PointF'

I am not sure why I got this error because I have already overloaded operator + for PointF.

```
 private static PointF operator+ (PointF point_left, PointF point_right) {
            return new PointF(point_left.X + point_right.X, point_left.Y + point_right.Y);
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
            List<PointF> pointList = new List<PointF>();
            PointF center = new PointF(50, 50);
            int radius = 50;
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
                double degree = (2.0 * Math.PI * i) / 5.0;
                PointF point = new PointF((float)(radius * Math.Cos(degree)), (float)(radius * Math.Sin(degree)));
                pointList.Add(point + center);
            }
            Brush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(new Point(20, 20), new Point(50, 50), 
                Color.Red, Color.Blue);
            e.Graphics.FillPolygon(brush, pointList.ToArray());
        }
```

Edit: After I re-compiled the code, I got a different error:

> one of the parameters of a binary operator must be the containing type

I really want to overload `+` operator for `PointF`. Is there any work around? In c++, is possible to overload operator for a different class by using a global function. How to achieve that for c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not extend built-in Structures and Classes to add an operator.

Alternatively you can create an extension method to get job done:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static PointF Add(this PointF operand1, PointF operand2)
    {
        return new PointF(operand1.X + operand2.X, operand1.Y + operand2.Y);
    }
}
```

And the usage is:

```
 var p1 = new PointF(1, 1);
 var p2 = new PointF(2, 2);
 reult =p1.Add(p2);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I like your solution. I learned something new: extension method

Answer (score 0):

According to C# [operator overloading rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), you must declare the operator overload as `public static`.  This could be the cause of your issue here, although I would be surprised if there wasn't an error for that too.